# ascii and siunitx packages collide

Tags: macros, siunitx, incompatibility

I want to load both the `ascii` package and the `siunitx` package. The problem is that both define a symbol `\SI`. Is there any way to make both packages work together?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can "store" the functionality of `ascii`s `\SI` macro in another (hitherto unused) macro (say, `\aSI`), then `\let\SI\relax` and then load the `siunitx` package. (Make sure before that no other package expects `\SI` to be `ascii`s variant.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ascii}

\let\aSI\SI

\let\SI\relax

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I just figured out that one could also use the [`savesym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/savesym) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{savesym}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\savesymbol{SI}
\usepackage{ascii}
\restoresymbol{a}{SI}


\begin{document}
\asciifamily

Some Text and \aSI. Some units \SI{2}{\m\per\second}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

See also https://texfaq.org/FAQ-alreadydef for a reference.